# Regular expression for restricted signed number formats

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, boost-regex

I want a regex for the following given pattern:

`{anynumber}` will return true.

`+{anynumber}` will return true.

`-{anynumber}` will return false.

`{anynumber}.5 OR {anynumber}.50 OR {anynumber}.500` and similar pattern will return true (i.e. any number of zeros after `.5`).

`+{anynumber}.5 / +{anynumber}.50 / +{anynumber}.500` and similar pattern will return true.

`-{anynumber}.5 / -{anynumber}.50 / -{anynumber}.500` and similar pattern will return false.

`+{anynumber}.6 / +{anynumber}.75 / +{anynumber}.205` and similar pattern will return false (i.e. after decimal point only `5` is allowed at the first place with any or no number of zeros afterwards).

No limitations of length of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

`^(?:(?: \/ )?[+]?[0-9]+(?:\.50*\b)?)+$`

And here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT2sU2/3).

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev,

21.55555 should return false. 

As I want only one 5 at the very first place. No other number will be allowed after first place except any / no number of zero(s)

Could you please modify the regex and post the correct one?

Comment: Hi @SwarupSaha, I updated the answer by adding `\b` to the non-capturing group. Now, it should not match `21.55555`.

Comment: If I add one more restriction like I want to allow {anynumber}.0 OR {anynumber}.00 (one or multiple time) to return true. What needs to be done?

Comment: You'll need to add an alternative `(?:50*|0)`, e.g. `^(?:(?: \/ )?[+]?[0-9]+(?:\.(?:50*|0)\b)?)+$` - see https://regex101.com/r/hT2sU2/4

Comment: 10.00 is returning false while 10.0 is returning true.. Could you please have a look and update me?

Comment: Here you are, a `+` quantifier should be added to `0`: `^(?:(?: \/ )?[+]?[0-9]+(?:\.(?:50*|0+)\b)?)+$`, see https://regex101.com/r/hT2sU2/5.